# How do I put a constant number infront of an entry space in html (js)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, python-3.x

I had 2 questions essentially. So I am a newbie to html and js. I am trying to create a form and put a space for users to enter their contact number(which is based in England so no international numbers), is there a way to put a constant number at the beginning of the entry space (like a constant +44 at the beginning after which they enter whatever their number is)?

+44________________

Also, this is a bit vague but there is also a place for age entry. Now is there a way to produce something like comboboxes in tkinter (I am more used to tkinter). The drop downs I saw were more like buttons but what I want is a 'readonly' typing space which produces a drop down menu when clicked on.
Any help is appreciated. thank you!

Comment: Do you mean a [`<select>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select) element for your second question?

Comment: @EmielZuurbier didnt see that earlier but yeah I mean that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.box__input {
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  outline: none !important;
}
.box__input:focus{
 border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
    <div class="box">
      <span class="box__txt">+44</span>
      <input type="text" class="box__input">
    </div>
```

Comment: just add color: #fff; to .box__txt tag